# Refresh site before routes work on angular deployed app in tomcat

Tags: angular, tomcat, angular2-routing, web-deployment

I'm deploying my application to tomcat server, I've already changed files to route deep links, rewrite url and so on. So all these things are working fine. The problem is that after I login I see the main page, if I click in a link that regularly takes me to other view, I see the url being updated but the content stills static for the main view.

This is for Angular 8, Using tomcat 8.x.x +

I made a workaround using

```
     if (localStorage.getItem("reload")) {
      localStorage.removeItem("reload");
      window.location.reload();
     }
    }
```

With these I control that if is the first time that I'm in the application, it will reload the app based on a local storage flag.

I expect to login into my application and navigate normally, instead of that I login and I need to manually hit refresh button or cmd+r or F5 or use my workaround to start navigating normally

//Edited:
This is how I navigate between components:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '', component: MainComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'main', component: MainComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'bcomp', component: BComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
]
```

There are no console errors, this is how I go to the other views:

```
<button id="menu-options-names" *ngFor="let option of optionsMenu" (click)="redirectTo(option.redirectsTo)">{{option.name}}</button>

redirectTo(redirectPath: any) {
    this.router.navigate([redirectPath]);
}
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in your browser console? Could you share some parts of your code how you navigate between routes and a small snippet of your router config which is broken? Or a small repository where you reproduce the issue?

Comment: Just edited the question @ZoltánSzepesi, unfortunately I can't create a small repo 'cause it's gonna work normally. the issue is when you deploy to Tomcat